# Change list length with comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'd like to do something like this:

```
Input: [3, 4, 1, 2]
Output:  ["3", "", "", "4", "", "", "1", "", "", "2", "", ""]
```

I know that

```
x = [3, 4, 1, 2]
[str(i) for i in x]
```

will produce the list without the extra empty strings. My question is whether there's an easy way to make Python go ahead and create 3 output items for each input item in a comprehension. If not, I can certainly write a loop...

Comment: Where is `1` in your sample output?

Comment: Are you sure a list is what you want? If you want to relate some strings to each number, you may be better off using something like a dict.

Comment: The list of numbers is an abtraction of the thing I really need; my question really is about how to produce such a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double for loop in list-comprehension acts like `map` + `chain` which you can make use of:

```
[j for i in x for j in [str(i), "", ""]]
# ['3', '', '', '4', '', '', '1', '', '', '2', '', '']
```

---

With `map` and `chain` syntax, you can do:

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain.from_iterable([str(i), "", ""] for i in x))
# ['3', '', '', '4', '', '', '1', '', '', '2', '', '']
```

Comment: Just what I needed, and the map/chain approach appeals to the Schemer in me, too. :)

Comment: @Psidom: could you please explain how your first snippet of code works. It looks wonderfully elegant.

Comment: @trinkner It's a nested for loop. Firstly loop through vector x and for each element x construct a new list `[str(i), "", ""]` as required by the OP and j will loop through this new list and put each element into the result list. This acts like a map + flatten.

Answer (score 1):

You may also achieve this using `zip` with *list comprehension* as:

```
>>> my_list = [3, 4, 1, 2]
>>> empty_list = [""] * len(my_list)

>>> [i for z in zip(my_list, empty_list, empty_list) for i in z]
[3, '', '', 4, '', '', 1, '', '', 2, '', '']
```

OR using `itertools.chain` along with `zip` as:

```
>>> from itertools import chain

>>> list(chain(*zip(my_list, empty_list, empty_list)))
[3, '', '', 4, '', '', 1, '', '', 2, '', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use list comprehension, but produce three-string blocks, and later concatenate them:

```
sum([[str(i), "", ""] for i in x], [])
# ['3', '', '', '4', '', '', '1', '', '', '2', '', '']
```